# How to write an abort-able synchronous method?

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-3.5, asynchronous

I need to run a list of methods synchronously, with the ability to stop the execution list. It's easy to stop the loop before execution using a reset event (see first line in `Execute`).

How can I wait for a response from `action.Execute()` and `action.Execute()` at the same time?

```
private ManualResetEvent _abortingToken = new ManualResetEvent(false);
private List<IAction> _actions;

public void Abort()
{
    _abortingToken.Set();
}

public void Execute()
{
    foreach (var action in _actions)
    {
        if (_abortingToken.WaitOne(0))
            break; // Execution aborted.

        action.Execute(); // Somehow, I need to call this without blocking

        while (/*Execute not finished*/)
        {
            if (_abortingToken.WaitOne(1))
                action.Abort();
        }
    }
}
```

I think it would be easy to preform using Tasks, but unfortunately I'm using .net 3.5.

---

**Edit:** solution inspired by [SLaks answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4984732/how-to-write-an-abort-able-synchronous-method/4984757#4984757):

```
public void Execute()
{
    Action execute = null;
    IAsyncResult result = null;

    foreach (var action in _actions)
    {
        execute = new Action(scriptCommand.Execute);

        if (_abortingToken.WaitOne(0))
            break; // Execution aborted.

        result = execute.BeginInvoke(null, null);

        while (!result.IsCompleted)
        {
            if (_abortingToken.WaitOne(10))
            {
                action.Abort();
                break;
            }
        }

        execute.EndInvoke(result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the opposite of synchronicity.
You need to run the method on a background thread.

For example, you can call the method using `Delegate.BeginInvoke`, then check `IAsyncResult.IsCompleted`.  (and make sure to call `EndInvoke` afterwards)

Comment: Thank you. Using `BeginInvoke` creates a very elegant code without a lot of overhead. But must I call `EndInvoke`? Isn't the sole purpose of `EndInvoke` is retrieving the return value or exceptions? What if I don't care for the result (i.e. after abort)?

Comment: @HuBeZa: If you don't call `EndInvoke`, you'll leak memory.

Answer (score 0):

You can run Execute in another Thread, and then your while tries to Join with a timeout.

```
public void Execute()
{
    foreach (var action in _actions)
    {
        if (_abortingToken.WaitOne(0))
            break; // Execution aborted.

        var workThread = new Thread(action.Execute); 
        workThread.Start();

        while (!workThread.Join(100)) /Milliseconds, there is also a timespan overload
        {
            if (_abortingToken.WaitOne(1))
                action.Abort();
        }
    }
}
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread_methods.aspx.